# How the heck do I import my python chatbot into my html code?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I trained a chatbot in a file on my computer. I have everything else for my website up and running but I cannot get the python file into the site. Do you have any advice for how I can make an html messenger that uses user inputs and converses with the AI chatbot that way? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to do this is by building a server, where you can have your chatbot code. You can use Flask. The instant the HTML asks a question, you send an API call with the required message, which when received by the API runs that message through the chatbot and returns the response in the output. This can continuously go on in the chat.

Comment: any place where I can read how to do that? or is there a youtube for it?

Comment: the easiest way is following: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world . As you start working, you'll realise the easier way is to build APIs in Flask. But, start studying the above blog post, and move ahead from there